# How often can I ping Google Calendar without getting banned?

Tags: google-calendar-api, scheduling

We are writing our custom scheduling app for our website.

Necessarily, it requests Google Calendar data to see when one of our 3 team members are available and then offers the visitor an array of available time slots.

Problem is, this takes too damn long to get the updated info.

I'm wondering if we could simply get all this data in the background and offer visitors to pick from data that is a few seconds old :)

So my question is, how often can we initiate this without getting banned by Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. The limit you're looking for depends on the type of google account you're using.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Also you won't get banned, it just won't run. If you're on a consumer account you could ping it 1x every 18 seconds without it failing. That's as close as you can get to "Live Data".